# Separating uncoutable number of sets preserving the sum

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering -- can we make a construction that separates uncountable number of non-empty sets so that we get the same amount of elements in their sum, but our new sets are disjoint?

Namely, if $$\left|\bigcup_\limits{\alpha < \omega_1}A_{\alpha}\right|\geq\aleph_{1},$$ can we somehow construct $B_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset$ so that for any $\beta\neq\gamma,\  B_{\beta}\cap B_{\gamma}=\emptyset$ and $\forall{\alpha}\  B_{\alpha}\subseteq A_{\alpha}$ and $$\bigcup_\limits{\alpha < \omega_1}B_{\alpha} = \bigcup_\limits{\alpha < \omega_1}A_{\alpha}?$$
Or can we at least get $$\left|\bigcup_\limits{\alpha < \omega_1}B_{\alpha}\right|\geq\aleph_{1}?$$

I think I know how to proceed, if we had at most countably many sets, but here limit steps are involved and a simple induction will not suffice. I don't see a way to use transfinite induction either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a pairwise disjoint family $\{B_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ such that $\varnothing\ne B_\xi\subseteq A_\xi$ for each $\xi<\omega_1$ and

$$\left|\bigcup_{\xi<\omega_1}B_\xi\right|=\left|\bigcup_{\xi<\omega_1}A_\xi\right|\;,$$

then there is an injection $\varphi:\omega_1\to\bigcup_{\xi<\omega_1}A_\xi$ such that $\varphi(\xi)\in A_\xi$ for each $\xi<\omega_1$. This fails if, for instance, $A_0=\{0\}$, $A_1=\{1\}$, $A_2=\{0,1\}$, and $A_\xi=\{\xi\}$ for $3\le\xi<\omega_1$. Thus, a necessary condition is that the family $\mathscr{A}=\{A_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ have a system of distinct representatives (SDR).

Conversely, if there is such an injective $\varphi:\omega_1\to\bigcup\mathscr{A}$, for each $x\in\left(\bigcup\mathscr{A}\right)\setminus\varphi[\omega_1]$ let $\psi(x)=\min\{\xi<\omega_1:x\in A_\xi\}$, and for each $\xi<\omega_1$ let $B_\xi=\{\varphi(\xi)\}\cup\psi^{-1}[\{\xi\}]$; then $\varnothing\ne B_\xi\subseteq A_\xi$, and $\bigcup_{\xi<\omega_1}B_\xi=\bigcup\mathscr{A}$.

If the sets $A_\xi$ are finite, the infinite version of Hall’s marriage theorem says that $\mathscr{A}$ has an SDR iff

$$\left|\bigcup_{\xi\in F}A_\xi\right|\ge|F|$$

for each finite $F\subseteq\omega_1$.